# Removing a junction folder in an MVC app.

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am looking at an MVC / Webforms hybrid application, where the Webforms part of the application is being supplied by a junction folder (hard symbolic link) point into the previous WebForms only incarnation of the project. In other words, MVC Proj has a junction folder pointing to a folder within the original WebForms application.

Since these two projects ought to be separate in their own right, and also since I would like to be able to use conventional tooling for Continuous Integration / Deployment etc, I would like to do away with the junction folder and manage this some other way.

One approach would be to replace the junction folder with a normal folder and simply copy over the content, but this would mean losing all the history etc on TFS. It’s a last resort option.

Is anyone aware of any other mechanism by which I can get the pages from a WebForms project to appear within an MVC application?

Comment: You want it to appear within when developing, when deploying, or both?

Comment: Both really... It's a weird problem...

Comment: What are you using for source code control? TFSVC or Git?

Comment: TFS - Visual Studio Online

Comment: Well I know pretty much nothing about that. If you were using Git, then [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) would be available to you.

Comment: I'll have a read of that and see if there is anything similar...